# search and tar files respecting folder structure?

Tags: command-line, tar

I'd like to search for all csv files in a few "date" subfolders, and then tar them preserving that structure, since the date is only at the level of folder, not file. So, for example I have

```
20200101
   A.csv
   B.py
20200102
   G.csv
   D.csv
   F.c
```

So, I'd like to have a `tar` with

```
20200101
   A.csv
20200102
   G.csv
   D.csv
```

I've tried:

`ls 20200*/<some regex>.* | xargs -n1 tar -vczf odlists.tar.gz`

But it only saves one file!

Answer (score 3):

`xargs -n1` means to execute the command for each argument. So `tar` saves one file at a time, overwriting the previous archive each time.

Even without `-n1`, the command would be fragile due to the command line length limit. `… | xargs tar …` makes repeated calls to `tar` if all the arguments can't fit at once, and each repeated call would overwrite the previous one.

You can create an archive with one file (or more) with `tar -c`, then append to it repeatedly with `tar -r`. That's awkward because there's no convenient way to pass different options the first time, and you have to create an uncompressed archive then compress it at the end.

If your tar supports the `-T` option, you can use it to pass file names on standard input. This works like `xargs`, but without the limitations of the command line length.

```
printf '%s\n' 20200*/*.csv | tar -vczf odlists.tar.gz -T -
```

Alternatively, assuming your tar supports filtering, you can use that.

```
tar -vczf odlists.tar.gz --exclude='*.' 2020*
```